# Newton's method: matrix multiplication

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

To compute an iteration of Newton's method, I need to multiply a gradient vector (G) with a hessian matrix (H).

But my hessian matrix has dimension $2\times2$ and my gradient vector dimension $2\times1$.

Since they are called `vector` and `matrix`, I guess this is correct.

But now how do I compute $G * H^{-1}$ ? Because the dimensions aren't equal?

Comment: You need to compute $H^{-1} G$. You can multiply a 2 by 2 matrix and a 2 by 1 matrix in the standard way.

Comment: The Wikipedia article might help you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method_in_optimization#Higher_dimensions